# jQuery I'm using not detecting CSS body:after

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm using some jQuery to detect whether a certain media query is triggered, something like this:

**jQuery**

```
var currentSize = "default";
var mqCSS = function () {
    var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').getPropertyValue('content');
    size = size.replace(/"/g, "");
    size = size.replace(/'/g, "");
    return size;
};

function mobile_load_img(obj) {
    size = obj();
    if (size != currentSize) {
        if (size == 'laptop') {
              alert('hello');
            currentSize = 'mobile';
        }
    } //if size

}
mobile_load_img(mqCSS);
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 10em) {
    body:after {
        content:'laptop';
        display:none;
    }
}
```

This should work, and it does on my home page but only any other page it doesn't work. The scripts are definitely loading.

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/4MW7v/)

The only other problem I can think of, is perhaps how I'm enqueue' my scripts. I'm not sure why but I think this problem occurred when I started to set `tilemtime()` to stop some CDN caching. I Don't quite know why because they all appear fine.

Sorry for the blocks of code:

**PHP**

```
function lart_stylesheets() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_style('reset_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/reset.css',
        array(), 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('base_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/base_style.css',
        array('reset_style'), '1.0', 'all');
    }
    if (is_home()) {
        wp_enqueue_style('home-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/home.css', array(), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/css/home.css'));
    }
    if (is_single() || is_page('LART TV') || is_category() || is_page('We\'re Wearing') || is_page('archives')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('single-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/single.css', array(), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/css/single.css'));
        wp_enqueue_style('lightbox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/lightbox.css',
        array(), '1.0', 'all');
    }
}

function lart_front_end_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-migrate.min');
    wp_deregister_script('comment-reply.min');
    wp_register_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', false, '3.6', true);
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script('mainJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/mainJS.js', array('jquery', 'underscore'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/mainJS.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('mainJS');
        wp_register_script('hammer', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/hammer.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/hammer.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('hammer');
    }
    if (is_home()) {
        wp_register_script('homeJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/home.js', array('jquery', 'underscore', 'jquery-masonry'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/home.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('homeJS');
    }
    if (is_single() || is_page('LART TV') || is_category() || is_page('We\'re Wearing')) {
        wp_register_script('singleJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/single.js', array('jquery', 'carousel'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/single.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('singleJS');
        wp_register_script('lightbox', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lightbox.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/lightbox.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('lightbox');
        wp_register_script('inviewJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/inview.js', array('jquery', 'singleJS'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/inview.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('inviewJS');
        wp_register_script('spinJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/spin.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/spin.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('spinJS');
        wp_register_script('carousel', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/carousel.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/carousel.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('carousel');
    }
    if (is_page('LART TV')) {
        wp_register_script('lartTVJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lartTV.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-masonry'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/lartTV.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('lartTVJS');
    }
    if (is_page('We\'re Wearing')) {
        wp_register_script('whatwearingJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/whatwearing.js', array('jquery-masonry'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/whatwearing.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('whatwearingJS');
    }
    if (is_search() || is_page('archives')) {
        wp_register_script('archiveJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/archive.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/archive.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('archiveJS');
        wp_register_script('spinJS', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/spin.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/spin.js'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('spinJS');
    }
} //End add_scripts
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong enqueue' my scripts and stylesheets?

Perhaps a timing issue or something?

Comment: Your regex for `replace` is wrong. It should be `size = size.replace("/\"/g", "");` `size = size.replace("/'/g", "");`

Comment: Why not use [`Window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) instead?

Comment: @Bojangles That definitely seems like a better option.

Comment: @imtheman thanks, I've changed that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: thanks @Bojangles I'll look into that in a bit, but I'd like to focus on this problem first.

Comment: Using `matchMedia` will _solve_ your problem. Your question is a good case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm just solving for `Y` :)

Comment: @Bojangles Will it? It's weird though as it worked before I fiddled with my enqueue scripts. Okay, I'll give it a shot anyway :) thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bojangles I'm still not sure *why* it didn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I don't get (maybe browser's lazy computing), if `display:none;` is set, the style isn't computed (at least at page load), so you can't access it via `window.getComputedStyle()`. 
I tested this by simply alert the `size` variable.

One workaround is to use `visibility:hidden;` on your style :

```
body:after {
    content:'laptop';
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4MW7v/1/), but you should consider using @Bojangles option, `window.matchMedia` ; it'll replace all your code with this piece of code :

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 10em)").matches)
    currentSize = 'mobile';
```

Comment: Brilliant! So you don't have to put quotes around the regex for the replace method? It works both ways. Is one better practice than the other?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. I was apprehensive using it because the code has been working fine up until now and it's been pretty faithful.

Comment: @imtheman It depends on how you use it : *To indicate strings, the parameters to the literal notation do not use quotation marks while the parameters to the constructor function do use quotation marks.* Quoted from this [MDN reference on RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: One argument against `window.matchMedia` is code duplication. When using the `:after` element, you define your media queries in css and only in css. Whereas using matchMedia you have to write your query again in javascript. In case you redefine your breakpoints afterwards, you'll have to rewrite those queries in two totally different locations.

Comment: @Nirazul that's why I went the css route I didn't really look into a js route as I'm using this query a lot.

Comment: @Nirazul True, but as the OP used media queries only to detect screen sizes (thus, using the `after` pseudo-element to store hidden information), I guess he won't have use of CSS's media-queries anymore (until he actually adapt his style with media queries)